# Accessing Errors-object in a Spring Webflow 2.0 test

Tags: validation, spring-webflow

How do I access the Errors-object created by spring when validation fails from a Spring Webflow 2.0 test (inherits from AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests)?

I tried using the FormObjectAccessor.getCurrentFormErrors() but I couldn't get a reference to the RequestContext.

Answer (score 2):

What is the reason you want to access the errors? Wouldn't it be simpler to write unit tests for your validation methods?